# Sequent calculus and renaming variable

Tags: logic

I have some questions regarding sequent calculus and renaming variable. The first two questions are general questions about rules and the other two are related to some examples.

1. [Logical rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRFIJ.png)

These rules says that we should choose a term "t" to replace "x". But my question is which "t" do we choose and how do we proceed to choose the right one (see examples 1 and 2) ?

2. [Logical rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nt2VU.png)

This rule says that "x" must not occur free anywhere, otherwise we can't use it. But if we come to a situation where "x" is free somewhere, do we have to rename it so that we can use the rule ?

**Regarding examples :**

1. [Example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl7aT.png)
   In this example, I don't understand why "y" is replaced by "z" (1), it doesn't say in the rule that we must do this. For (2), we applied the rule and replaced "y" by a term "z". Did we choose "z" purposefully ?
2. [Example 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyS6q.png)
   I have the same kind of question for this one. We replaced the variable "x" by "z". Does it make a difference if we have chosen another variable like "a" or did we choose "z" purposefully ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to math.SE!

> But my question is which "t" do we choose and how do we proceed to
>   choose the right one (see examples 1 and 2) ?

Think about how you would write proofs in the real world. If an exam asked you to prove that discontinuous functions exist, you would write something like "*Consider the function $x \mapsto \mathrm{sgn}(x)$...*", and then you would follow that by writing a proof that $x \mapsto \mathrm{sgn}(x)$ is discontinuous.

Nothing stops you from writing "*Consider the function $x \mapsto x^2$...*" instead, except for the fact that you won't be able to finish the proof that way: you can't prove that $x \mapsto x^2$ is discontinuous (because it isn't).

Formally, what you're doing while writing the exam amounts to using $D_\exists$ on the formula $\exists x. \neg \mathrm{continuous}(x)$, choosing $t$ to be $x \mapsto \mathrm{sgn}(x)$, and then finishing with a proof of $\neg \mathrm{continuous}(t)$.

There is no general method for choosing $t$. To choose the appropriate $t$, you need to know why the thing that you're trying to prove actually holds.

> This rule says that "x" must not occur free anywhere, otherwise we
>   can't use it. But if we come to a situation where "x" is free
>   somewhere, do we have to rename it so that we can use the rule ?

That is correct.

> In this example, I don't understand why "y" is replaced by "z" (1),
>   it doesn't say in the rule that we must do this. For (2), we applied
>   the rule and replaced "y" by a term "z". Did we choose "z"
>   purposefully ?

Yes. In the first example, we made two choices, since we had two $D_\exists$ rules. First, we chose $t$ to be $z$, and then we chose $t$ to be $x$. This was done purposefully: we had $P(x,z)$ on the left of the turnstile ($\vdash$). To finish the proof, we needed to have the same thing on both the left and the right. But these choices of $t$ were the only ones that could achieve this objective.

If it helps, you can think of $P(x,z) \vdash \exists y. \exists x. P(x,y)$ as the following exam question: "*given that $z$ is the parent of $x$, prove that there are two people such that one is the parent of the other*". You would just say "well, sure, in particular z is the parent of x", and conclude the proof. But this is exactly what the formal uses of $D_\exists$ amount to.

> I have the same kind of question for this one. We replaced the
>   variable "x" by "z". Does it make a difference if we have chosen
>   another variable like "a" or did we choose "z" purposefully ?

The choice matters, for essentially the same reason. We have $R(z)$ on the left-hand side. The finish the proof, we have to have the same formula appear on both sides of the turnstile. So $z$ is a good choice: it ensures that we will eventually have $R(z)$ on the right-hand side as well.

Substituting $a$ instead of $z$ would have left us with $R(z), R(y) \vdash R(a)$, and there's no way to continue that proof: none of the rules can be applied.

(What about substituting $y$? That would not work either: I'll leave you to think about why.)

Comment: That was so well explained, thank you ! And I believe that we must choose z over y to avoid confusion because y is referring to the universal quantifier ?